# Handling a lot of EditText data in Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am making some kind of table-like **EditText** that is 5 x 9 size.

So I first gave each of the **45 EditTexts** separate ids, but I'm keep thinking that it's too inconvenient to handle.

Is there any way to handle these 45 Strings more conveniently??

Comment: Why don't you use ```RecyclerView```  or ```ListView``` for these 45 editText. That will be easiest way to handler ?

Comment: @Afsaredrisy But isn't it same that you have to give each of the editText seperate ids to "getText" each of them?

Comment: Can you update your questions by uploading view of your 45 EditTexts. And what exactly you want to do with these EditText is just getting text from all of these or something else.

Comment: Definitely, not an easy way. You can use the recyclerview.. and make a custom adapter to get the text based on their position..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do it as below :)

**First:** declare an **Id** for your **root element** in your layout
(if you're working on **fragments** you don't need to declare id and you can simply get root View in **onViewCreated**)

**Second**:
 Loop your root layout and get its childs texts if they are EditText

> Final code in Activity :

```
    List<String> inputs=new ArrayList<>();
    LinearLayout rootView=findViewById(R.id.yourrootElementId);

      //if your root element type is not LineareLayout replace LinearLayout with your root 
     //element type for Example ConstraintLayout
    for (int i = 0; i < rootView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = rootView.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof EditText)
        {
            String text=((EditText) child).getText().toString().trim();
            inputs.add(text);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout). Set columnCount to 5 and rowCount to 9.

```
<GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="5"
        android:rowCount="9"
        android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:background="@drawable/box_background"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:background="@drawable/box_background"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"/>

            .......

</GridLayout>
```

The code above uses weight attributes for auto-stretching. This requires minimum api level 21. If you don't need auto-stretching, you could still use GridLayout without the weight attributes.

If you need auto-stretching below 21, then you can use LinearLayout. One vertical LinearLayout for the entire table and one horizontal LinearLayout for each row.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/box_background"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/box_background"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/box_background"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/box_background"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/box_background"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/box_background"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/box_background"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/box_background"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/box_background"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/box_background"/>
    </LinearLayout>

..........

</LinearLayout>
```

### Result:

[image]

Comment: Hmm. I think I misread the question. But my answer gives some good information. I'll just delete it once it gets downvotes.